# Duplicity (Duply) over SCP very slow. What to look for?

Tags: scp, duplicity

I'm struggling to setup a simple backup routine to go from my local fileserver over to my friend's server (both Ubuntu 18.04).

I finally got it all 'working', but when I do a test of a 750Mb fileset, it took over 26 minutes to complete (that would take 15 days for 1 TB!).

But here's the thing... if instead of SCP to the remote server, I do a local "file://" backup (otherwise identical backup) it takes < 30 seconds.  OK, so it isn't the backup generation.  It must be the transfer, right?  But when I do a manual SCP of the resulting local backup to the remote server, that same 750 Mb takes < 30 seconds as I'd expect given mine and my friend's bandwidth.  So it isn't the transfer speed.

If it isn't duplicity making the backup and it isn't SCP sending it... what do I look for as to what the problem could be?

Thanks.

Below is the config file for Duply (uncommented lines only).

```
GPG_KEY='[my key ID]'
GPG_PW='[GPG passphrase]'
TARGET='scp://user@friends_server.duckdns.org//mnt/bigdisk/backup'
SOURCE='/mnt/bigdisk/Books'
```

When doing the local, the only thing I changed was the TARGET to:

```
TARGET='file:///mnt/bigdisk/backup'
```

Now obviously I could script it to do a local and then SCP over rather than SCP within Duply/Duplicity, but that seems dumb.

Comment: (1.) what is your duplicity version? (2.) what is the speed if you manually scp data to the backend box?

Comment: @ede 1)  0.7.17. 2) answered in my question: 'when I do a manual SCP of the resulting local backup to the remote server, that same 750 Mb takes < 30 seconds".  Thanks

Comment: Incidentally, I've moved on to rdiff-backup and it works at a good speed.  I'd rather use duplicity for the encryption though.

Answer (score 0):

duplicity 0.7 is not maintained anymore. might be fixed in 0.8.

default duplicity ssh backend uses paramiko. might be a bug in there. check for a more recent version.

alternatively try sftp:// if possible or switch to another ssh backend as explained in the man page

http://duplicity.nongnu.org/vers8/duplicity.1.html#sect26 a Note on Ssh Backends

http://duplicity.nongnu.org/vers8/duplicity.1.html#sect7 section SCP/SFTP access

..ede/duply.net